# How to match db result-row date field as string?

Tags: karate

I have some input strings to be compared to what it has been inserted in a DB by a rest call. When I extract the result set with readRows I get a java object with date fields, how can I compare them to the original strings? A direct match gives the following error:

```
actual: 2021-01-28, expected: '2021-1-28', reason: actual value is not a string
```

Do I need to convert the java object somehow? I tried to convert it to JSON but I get the same error.